# Operator Norm of a Self-adjoint Operator

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis

I am trying to prove  $\|A\|=\sup_{||x||\leq 1}|\langle x,Ax\rangle|$ for a self adjoint bounded linear operator $A$ on a complex Hilbert space. I know how to prove $\|A\|\geq\sup_{||x||\leq 1}|\langle x,Ax\rangle|$. For the converse, however,
$$ \|A\| = \sup_{||x||\leq 1} \| Ax \|$$
$$ =  \sup_{||x||\leq 1} \langle Ax,Ax\rangle^{1/2}$$
$$ =  \sup_{||x||\leq 1} \langle  x,A^*Ax\rangle^{1/2} $$
$$ =  \sup_{||x||\leq 1} \langle  x,A^2x\rangle^{1/2} $$
And then I'm stuck!

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/859328/norm-of-self-adjoint-operator

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One can easily verify that $\|A\|=\sup\{|\langle Ax,y\rangle| : x,y \in \mathcal H,\
\|x\|=\|y\|=1\}$ in a complex Hilbert space $\mathcal H$.

Notice that $$\langle A(x+y), x+y\rangle − \langle A(x- y), x- y\rangle = 2\langle Ax,y\rangle+2\langle Ay,x\rangle.$$ Since $A$ is self adjoint, $\langle Ay,x\rangle=\langle y,Ax\rangle=\overline{\langle Ax,y\rangle}.$ So $$\langle A(x+y), x+y\rangle − \langle A(x- y), x- y\rangle=4\newcommand{\re}{\operatorname{Re}}\re\langle Ax,y\rangle.$$
Let $P:=\sup_{||x||\leq 1}|\langle x,Ax\rangle|.$ Then 
$$\begin{align*}
|4\re\langle Ax,y\rangle|
&=|\langle A(x+y), x+y\rangle − \langle A(x- y), x- y\rangle |\\
&\leq P\|x+y\|^2+P\|x-y\|^2\\
&=2P(\|x\|^2+\|y\|^2).
\end{align*}$$
So, whenever $\|x\|=\|y\|=1$, we have $$|\re\langle Ax,y\rangle|\leq P\tag{$\color{red}{1}$}\label1.$$

Suppose $\langle Ax,y\rangle=re^{i\theta}$ with $\|x\|=\|y\|=1$. I will construct an element  $z$ with $\|z\|=1$ such that $|\langle Ax,y\rangle|=|\re\langle Az,y\rangle|$. Then we can apply  $(\ref 1)$ to $|\re\langle Az,y\rangle|$ and we will get $|\langle Ax,y\rangle|\leq P $.

Consider $z=e^{-i\theta} x$. Then $\|z\|=1$. Also, note that $$\langle Az,y\rangle=e^{-i\theta}\langle Ax,y\rangle=r=\re\langle Az,y\rangle,$$ and $|\langle Ax,y\rangle|=r$. So $$|\langle Ax,y\rangle|=r=|\re\langle Az,y\rangle|\leq P.$$ Hence $\|A\|\leq P$.

I learnt this proof from  *Functional Analysis* by B.V. Limaye.

Comment: Can you please explain how you got $|\langle A(x+y), x+y\rangle − \langle A(x- y), x- y\rangle |\leq P\|x+y\|^2+P\|x-y\|^2$?

Comment: For the future readers, the answer is here: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3440029/371990