# An application of parallelogram equality

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm trying to understand how the following inequality is derived.

Let $A$ be a self-adjoint linear and bounded operator in a complex Hilbert space. 
Let $P:=\sup_{||x||\leq 1}|\langle x,Ax\rangle|.$ Then 
$$\begin{align*} 
& |\langle A(x+y), x+y\rangle − \langle A(x- y), x- y\rangle |\\
&\leq P\|x+y\|^2+P\|x-y\|^2\\
&=2P(\|x\|^2+\|y\|^2).
\end{align*}$$

PS. I know that  $\|A\|=\sup\{|\langle Ax,y\rangle| : x,y \in \mathcal H,\
\|x\|=\|y\|=1\}$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$|\langle Ay , y \rangle| \leq P$ if $\|y\|\leq 1$. If $x \neq 0$ take $y=\frac x {\|x\|}$. Then $|\langle Ay , y \rangle| \leq P$ which gives (by linearity of $A$ and properties of inner product) $|\langle Ax , x \rangle| \leq P\|x\|^{2}$. For $x=0$ this is obvious.

The equality part follows by just expanding $\|x+y\|^{2} $ and $\|x-y\|^{2} $ in terms of the inner product.