# How to prove that $\|T\| \le \max \{ |m_1|, |m_2| \}$?

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, adjoint-operators

Let $(H, \langle \cdot, \cdot\rangle)$ be a real Hilbert space and $|\cdot|$ its induced norm. Let $T:H\to H$ be a self-adjoint bounded linear operator. Let $B_H$ be the closed unit ball of $H$.  Let $S$ be the unit sphere of $H$. Let
$$
\begin{align}
m_1 &:= \inf_{u\in S} \langle Tu, u\rangle,  \\
m_2 &:= \sup_{u\in S} \langle Tu, u\rangle.
\end{align}
$$

I would like to prove a result in my lecture notes, i.e.,

> $\|T\| = \max \{ |m_1|, |m_2| \}$.

Could you elaborate on how to prove the challenging direction $\|T\| \le \max \{ |m_1|, |m_2| \}$?

---

Clearly, $m_1 \le m_2$. By Cauchy–Schwarz inequality,
$$
\begin{align}
m_1 &\ge \inf_{u\in S} (-|Tu|) = -\|T\|,\\
m_2 &\le \sup_{u\in S} |Tu| = \|T\|.
\end{align}
$$

Then $-\|T\| \le m_1 \le m_2 \le \|T\|$. Then $\max \{ |m_1|, |m_2| \} \le \|T\|$.

Comment: Use this equivalence https://math.stackexchange.com/q/859328/27978 and note that it a real space.

Comment: @copper.hat I have formulated your idea as an answer below. Could you have a check on it? Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $m := \sup_{u\in S} |\langle Tu, u\rangle|$. [Then](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/859328/27978) $m=\|T\|$ because $T$ is self-adjoint. Let
$$
\begin{align}
S_+ &:= \{u \in S : \langle Tu, u\rangle \ge 0\}, \\
S_- &:= \{u \in S : \langle Tu, u\rangle < 0\}.
\end{align}
$$

WLOG, we assume $S_+ \neq \emptyset$ and $S_- \neq \emptyset$. Then
$$
\begin{align}
m_1 &= \inf_{u\in S_-} \langle Tu, u\rangle,  \\
m_2 &= \sup_{u\in S_+} \langle Tu, u\rangle, \\
m &= \max \{ m_2, - m_1 \}.
\end{align}
$$

Because $m_2 \le |m_2|$ and $-m_1 \le |m_1|$, we get $m \le \max \{ |m_1|, |m_2| \}$. The claim then follows.

Comment: Looks fine. Basically it is because for $A \subset \mathbb{R}$ we have $\sup_{t \in A} |t| = \max( \sup_{t \in A} t, \sup_{t \in A} -t )$.

Comment: @copper.hat Thank you so much for your verification!